# Hidden LED lights that are seen only by camera on my 3 Android devices

Tags: screen, camera

I accidentally found something hidden on the main screen of my Android devices: 1-4 blinking led lights that cannot be seen with the naked eye, but can be seen using the camera app. The location color and intensity of hidden lights vary phone to phone. Can anyone tell me what they are for? I found nothing in searches.

Comment: mention about three devices. Manufacturer, android version etc.

Comment: Proximity or ambient light sensor? I remember seeing those on a few rare devices, with *naked eye* also (faintly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are proximity sensor and  light sensor they emit infrared light that's why you can't see them with naked eyes. They are located near the top area of the front side of the phone. More can be read [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-proximity-sensor)